# Chrome Proxy Extension doesn't change IP

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I try to create extension which change IP when user clicked on button, but IP doesn't change and I don't have idea why. I tried many proxy hosts and IPs, but it doesn't change situation.

**popup.js**

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  const button = document.querySelector('.button')
  const config = {
    mode: 'fixed_servers',
    rules: {
      proxyForHttp: {
        scheme: 'socks5',
        host: '98.111.239.128',
        port: 56053
      },
      bypassList: ['foobar.com']
    }
  }

  // Enable proxy
  button.addEventListener('click', function() {
    return chrome.proxy.settings.set({
      value: config,
      scope: 'regular'
    }, function() {})
  })
})
```

**manifest.json**

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "VPN for vk.com",
  "description": "Easy VPN for visit vk.com",
  "version": "1.0",

  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "lib/src/img/icon.png",
    "default_popup": "lib/popup.html"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "storage",
    "proxy"
  ]
}
```

Comment: How are you testing this? Specifically, is it HTTP or HTTPS? Does chrome settings indicate that the proxy has been set?

Comment: After enable the extension I am going to visit anysite. Also I check proxy settings with call chrome.proxy.settings.get and here all okay.